# Spring Pitfalls

Tags: java, spring

As a relatively new comer to the Spring world, I figured it would be nice to have a community Wiki page that lists common pitfalls in Spring-based projects.

These include:

- Misunderstood concepts
- Popular features from Spring 2.X that are no longer recommeded in Spring 3.X
- Abused features
- Performance killers

Answer (score 3):

**Most abused and misunderstood concept:** Not everything need to be injected.

**Others:**

1. [Performance problems when using lots of AOP request scoped beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771774/performance-problems-when-using-lots-of-aop-request-scoped-beans) (perf)
2. Singleton beans are loaded differently in BeanFactory and ApplicationContext. A bean factory lazily loads all beans, deferring bean creation until the getBean() method is called. An application context loads all singleton beans upon context startup.
3. [Unified property management through Spring's new Environment abstraction in 3.1 rather than using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/?__utma=1.643617175.1286930853.1297912022.1298302346.68&__utmb=1.6.10.1298676959&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1298302346.68.75.utmcsr=googleutmccn=organicutmcmd=organicutmctr=hibernate%20and%20connect%20by&__utmv=-&__utmk=36645920)
4. [Other deprecated features](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/upgrade/spring3/html/ch03.html)

Answer (score 2):

Mixing Annotation-based configuration with XML-based configuration. Happens to me all the time...

Answer (score 1):

1. Calling public methods using `this` when inside a proxy-enriched bean. This is a recurring problem in StackOverflow, explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).
2. Injecting bean with `prototype` scope does not mean you'll have a new instance every time you use this bean. Explain `lookup-method`. Also: how to use session-scoped beans in singletons.
3. Spring can be used outside of the web container. Example of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.
4. Proper usage of Spring testing support. Explain default transaction behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start first. Use of DAO templates, such as JpaDaoSupport and JpaTemplate for JPA, is no longer recommended in Spring 3 in favour of direct use of JPA.